# php Cannot use string offset as an array even if var is an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have this error when reading a special key but my var is an array.

here is my code :

```
while($d <= count($nom)) {
    $last_d=$d;
    $nomdata = 'data_'.$d;
    $$nomdata = array();

    $di = 1;
    while($di <= count($data)) {
       if($data[$di][2] == sprintf('%08d', $d)) {
           array_push($$nomdata,$data[$di]);
       }
       $di++;
    }

    if(!empty($$nomdata)) {
        # THIS WON'T WORK -> echo '<br>i:'.$$nomdata[1][2].'<br>';
        # BUT THIS IS WORKING ↓
        print_r($$nomdata);
    }

    $d++;
}
```

When I print_r, I have the multidimensional array like I want it to be.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01556
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 00000002
        [3] =>           
        [4] => 34
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 2016/09/01  10:19:11
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01566
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 00000002
...
```

But when I call the $$nnomdata[1][2], (or $data_2[1][2]) I have this error :

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array
```

I really don't get it. The first array $data is the same type (multidimensional) and everything is ok. I can read $data[1][2], but since I transfer it in $data_1, $data_2, I can't read it anymore like that. But the keys seem to be ok when I print_r them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a lot of `$$` in your code. Are you sure you wanted to do that?

Comment: If you're using $$ you should probably just be using arrays. Is there any reason you don't just add a dimension to you're array?

Comment: Also which line is it throwing this error for?

Comment: @Machavity : Yep, there are variable variables.

Comment: @bluegman991 I have one multidimensionnal array $data . And i want to put all specifics rows (the ones that $data[$i][2] is the ID I'm looking for) in specifis arrays $data_$ID

Comment: Ok @patryk-uszynski found it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen in older php versions. 
`$nomdata` is string

When you access `$$nomdata` then php return variable by name stored in `$nomdata`

When you access `$$nomdata[x]` then php try to get `$nomdata[x]` as variable name

**Example PHP 5.0**

```
<?php

$test = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

$array = 'test';

var_dump( $$array );    // array
var_dump( $$array[0] ); // Undefined variable: t
var_dump( $$array[5] ); // Uninitialized string offset:  5
```

**Example PHP 7.0.5**

```
$test = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

$array = 'test';

var_dump( $$array );    // array
var_dump( $$array[0] ); // int(1)
var_dump( $$array[5] ); // int(6)
```

**Solution**

```
$myArray = $$nomdata;
var_dump($myArray[5]); //now you can access array fields

// if you want to modify them, you will need to create reference
$myArray = &$$nomdata;
$myArray[0] = 'some value'; // this will affect your source array
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, after my code (if I throw the two lines that calls the array). I have something else. And try to call $data_1 as $$nomdata is $data_$i. How can I access them ?
Thanks again.

Comment: Ah ! You are saying that I should try with PHP 7+ ?

Comment: @hellodracon make your variable like that: `$myArray = &$$nomdata;` then changes will affect source array

Comment: How do you call this ? When you put & before a variable varbiable ?

Comment: @hellodracon: the underlying problem here is that `$$nomdata[1][2]` is ambiguous; it could mean different things depending on the order the parser processes it. PHP7 changed the order of processing which will change how your code works compared with PHP5. The solution is to use braces or brackets to clarify for the parser what you mean. You need to write it like this: `($$nomdata)[1][2]`. That will solve it for you. However, I would also recommend not using variable variables like this; in 8 out of 10 cases they are a classic sign of bad coding style, and this is definitely one of the 8.

Comment: See also: [Changes to variable handling in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 0):

Check out the line you have commented out, I changed to something that would work for you. Basically PHP has a defined order in which variable variables are parsed which do differ between php versions.

```
while($d <= count($nom)) {
    $last_d=$d;
    $nomdata = 'data_'.$d;
    $$nomdata = array();

    $di = 1;
    while($di <= count($data)) {
       if($data[$di][2] == sprintf('%08d', $d)) {
           array_push($$nomdata,$data[$di]);
       }
       $di++;
    }

    if(!empty($$nomdata)) {
        # THIS WON'T WORK -> echo '<br>i:'.{$$nomdata}[1][2].'<br>';
        # BUT THIS IS WORKING ↓
        print_r($$nomdata);
    }

    $d++;
}
```

Comment: Nop :( I got this : syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/lekalif/www/heures.php on line 156